# JHipster application running in Docker container - Websocket error

Tags: spring-boot, jhipster, spring-websocket

I have a problem with a small JHipster based Application I'm trying to run on a server inside a Docker container.
The problem is with the Websocket connection:

`VM1772:35 WebSocket connection to 'ws://example.com/websocket/tracker/011/oxjwhn1s/websocket?access_token=ey…_TUTlIQeihPamU9Cr4AELuIqgnxZlAExhpBzRGwTtSBsQtC1_uMmwttUYgMmvhdbZhMLCS2RoA' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400`

(I changed actual domain name)

The app is running inside a Docker container that is built using a maven goal `docker:build`.
To be accessible only by domain name I'm using nginx reverse proxy that is also running inside a Docker container (https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy) and I think that header forwarding is setup OK inside nginx configuration:

```
proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_buffering off;
proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection $proxy_connection;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $proxy_x_forwarded_proto;
```

What am I missing to get this to work properly?

Answer (score 0):

I will to go trogh the next steps in order to locate the problem:

- try to run the application as standalone just to be sure that the Problem is not in the app.
- try running the app inside docker without proxy
- finaly if those two steps works then try to run the app behind a proxy just to be sure that you have the correct config for the proxy.

If this final step is ok then it need to be the docker config. In order do give you more option it will be good to have some more information from your logs.